# Error while adding two numbers in android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a button in Android Studio which adds two numbers when cicked on it in Android Studio but it is giving the error. Can you help me? I am a beginner in Android development.

```
d4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String str=inputField.getText().toString();
            char[] ch=str.toCharArray();
            int i;
            for(i=0; i<ch.length; i++){
                if(ch[i]=='+'){int Add=ch[i-1]+ch[i+1];
                inputField.setText(Add);}

            }

        }
    });
```

d4 is the id of the button and inputField is the id of the EditText

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I would like to suggest using this code:

        String[] array = s.split("\\+");
        int i = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) + Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
        System.out.println(i);
It will make your code more generic.

Answer (score 2):

Your setting int value to textView. so change int value into string like this

```
inputField.setText(Add.toString());
```

Comment: Could you consider to include the "why it works this way" and not just the solution in your answer above? The "why" in this case being the `setText(int)` expecting a string resource and not an arbitrary `int`

Comment: (I didn't wanna add my own answer since yours already helps the OP, but that piece of information would help future troubleshooters too )

Answer (score 0):

you aren't posting the error msg of the code but inspecting your snippet I see some cavities like this invalid index in the for loop

```
for(i=0; i<ch.length; i++){
     if(ch[i]=='+'){
         int Add=ch[i-1]+ch[i+1];
                     ^--here: when i is zero, you read try to get the 
                     element at index -1, this will cause an exception!
         inputField.setText(Add);
     }
}
```